# White text on white background in TinyMCE when wp_editor is called in WP 3.9

Tags: plugins, php, javascript, tinymce

One of the features of [my plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/author-customization/) is to add a TinyMCE editor instance inside a meta box on the Edit Post screen. This has worked great up until 3.9 and I'm not clear as to what's going wrong.

Here are the relevant files containing the code for the meta box editor (links to files inside Github commit):

- [admin/author-customization-admin.php](https://github.com/cconover/wp-author-customization/blob/f260165bae2f6c42e7d3158da62c81615ac9b096/admin/author-customization-admin.php)
- [admin/assets/js/edit-post.js](https://github.com/cconover/wp-author-customization/blob/f260165bae2f6c42e7d3158da62c81615ac9b096/admin/assets/js/edit-post.js)

What am I missing? This is what I'm given when I load the Edit Post screen:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/6GQUUa9.png]

The contents are there though, which you can see when you highlight inside the textarea:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/jTSlgWm.png]

On WordPress 3.8.1 the code works just fine:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/i7nTqPb.png]

I'm not sure whether it's an issue with the PHP code or the JavaScript. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can confirm that. See [ticket #26778](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/26778).

Comment: Can you edit to add the code that is actually initializing your editor? I've been working on TinyMCE all day, and it makes me want to yell and throw things. Do note that `tinymce.execCommand( 'mceAddControl', true, id );` changed to `tinymce.execCommand( 'mceAddEditor', true, id );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text goes white when the `id` attribute (`$editor_id`) contains `[]`. They are not allowed here.

Make sure the second argument for `wp_editor` does not contain `[]`, and the text becomes visible again. I have reported that regression with a test case on [ticket #26778](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/26778).

To use brackets in the `name` attribute, use `textarea_name` in the `settings` parameter.

#### Example

```
$editor_id   = 'my_editor_1';
$editor_name = 'my_editor[1]';
$settings    = array (
    'tabindex'      => FALSE,
    'editor_height' => 150,
    'resize'        => TRUE,
    'textarea_name' => $editor_name
);

wp_editor( $post->post_content, $editor_id, $settings );
```

Comment: That solved it! Thanks for the info (and for reporting it as a bug), I wouldn't have thought of that.